# No error, yet no output while executing a function involving tkinter and python-mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

My program makes use of tkinter and python-mysql connector.
With the click of a particular button in my program, the function ‘Headwear1’ is executed. This function is supposed to add a set of data in a table(named cart) if it doesn’t previously exist. Whereas, if the data is pre-existent, the same function should delete it from the table. On execution, not only there isn’t any desired output, but there’s no error message to take guidance from. Kindly suggest a valid code.
PS: I am a beginner and a simple code is appreciated. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector as ms
mycon=ms.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="******",database="cs")
mycur=mycon.cursor()
mycur.execute('drop table if exists CART')
mycur.execute('create table cart(Item_No int primary key, Product_Name varchar(50) not null, Price_INR int, Category varchar(20), Supplier varchar(100))')
q=('select * from cart')
mycur.execute(q)
results = mycur.fetchall()
rc=mycur.rowcount
def confirm1():
    messagebox.showinfo( "Message", "Added to your cart")

def confirm2():
    messagebox.showinfo( "Message", "Removed from your cart")

def Headwear1():
    for rc in results:
        if rc[0]==1 or rc[1]==1 or rc[2]==1 or rc[3]==1 or rc[4]==1 or rc[5]==1 or rc[6]==1 or rc[7]==1:
            Headwear1del()
        else:
            Headwear1add() 

def Headwear1del():
    mycur.execute("delete from cart where Item_no=1")
    mycon.commit()
    confirm2()

def Headwear1add():
    a=1 
    b='Premium Headband'
    c=399
    e='Headwear'
    f='SKUDGEAR'
    q="insert into cart values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')".format(a,b,c,e,f)
    mc=mycon.cursor()
    mc.execute(q)
    mycon.commit()
    confirm1()
```

Comment: Instead of using `rc=mycur.rowcount` use `len(results)`, also keep in mind, your `mycur.execute("delete from cart where Item_no=1")` will always delete the first item only.

Comment: Nothing in your code has to do with tkinter.